# Python regular expression for simple text formula

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use `re.split` to more easily tell if a formula used within a program I have created is valid or not, I am nearly there I guess but can't make it stop at the second double quote on the end of hello in the 2nd example:

```
import re

s = """c2+"hello"+c4"""
x = re.split("(\".+\"|\+)",s)
# output is correct here ['c2', '+', '', '"hello"', '', '+', 'c4']


# but not here:
s = """c2+"hello""+"c4"""
x = re.split("(\".+\"|\+)",s)
# current output ['c2', '+', '', '"hello""+"', 'c4']
# desired output ['c2', '+', '', '"hello"', '"+"', 'c4']
```

Comment: Triple-quote your regex like you did the string: `re.split("""(".+"|\+)""",s)` and save some escaping.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the part inside the double quotes non-greedy, using `.+?`:

```
import re

s = """c2+"hello""+"c4"""
x = re.split("(\".+?\"|\+)",s)
print(x)
# ['c2', '+', '', '"hello"', '', '"+"', 'c4']
```

Note that there is a difference with your expected output: the empty string between "hello" and "+". This is on purpose, so that the separators always appear at odd indices (and the other parts of the string at even indices) in the resulting list.

Comment: I'd also suggest using single-quotes to wrap the regex so the extra escaping work isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure but this might work also re.split('("[^"]*"|\+)',s)